# How would one go about referencing an audio file from a relative path?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a hobby project in JavaFX and want to play some music. I currently reference the entire file path when I put in the song, which looks something like C Drive -> Games ->myGame -> Audio -> song.mp3.

However, this would mess it up if I moved the file or another user would install it somewhere else. How do I create a relative path to the song file?

```
Media song= new Media("file:///E:/games/gameName/audio/song.mp3");
player= new MediaPlayer(song);
player.play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to load media relative to Application directory:

```
Media song= new Media(new File("./audio/song.mp3").toURI().toString());
```

[image]

Comment: That file's location is relative to the working directory when running the program. this may or may not be the directory the program is stored in. Running the program from the command line you can easily launch the app with a different working directory...